# Typescript discriminated union based on array membership

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Is it possible to have something like this?

```
{
   roles: contains "admin",
   admin_details: string
} && {
   roles: contains "vendor",
   vendor_details: string
}
```

?

I figure probably not. What would be the cleanest way to get this sort of behavior, where a type has details depending on what roles they have?

The only way I could think of it was having something like:

```
({
   is_admin: true,
   admin_details: string
} | 
{ is_admin: false,
  admin_details: undefined
}) 
&& ({
   is_vendor: true,
   vendor_details: string
} | 
{ is_vendor: false,
  vendor_details: undefined
});
```

And adding those additional is_role field on role creation/change. But this is pretty verbose. Is it a good solution, or would you recommend something else?

Thanks!

edit: maybe a union between Admin and Vendor interfaces, with a type guard that examines array membership would be cleaner?

edit: I attempted to use the code in the first answer, but am having issues. See the updated playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBASgewDZQLIEMIwLwwN7AwzoAmAtgJYB2AXPsedQPolQjoVIDOdXIATtQDmMAL6EYANyhUSCfnTxSZc-izYduvAcLHBxoSLACCSJAAUo-MgFd2ICgipcAPABUYUAB4gVXGHyCVEIAfDgwANpuALqePn6RVFDS-LEA-JGxihIRANIw1DAxdKYWVrb2js4uAKJeAMZINqzuADQwuSFh3r6y-tQAZlYwAKpxvST+gcIR0RJEGXntAHSrI7EAPqPzMHRJKfpRc4bQo1RVbggAklS+-FxQ9Q5OLiNhuBIAFGM9CehUYBgGU+AGs6CMAJTYEKSBAUEi7GD7KwQ8YJT6guiDYZXKEwuEkVEZK6I5H8YAnWCIFD+XClSzWOzoZ7VEFQMAIAbwZBoTDdeJ9ApUIb8UZowXTYKzCQZH4CyaZHYZMk7OifJQ7Ij8Hk8bZEIiiGAAMjOF2utysDyeVRcBH1+ryQtGESoNjIACMrNFonRqbyII6TWyOVy-RgIHN7aIIiMXW7PaloiFUb9BdjRQB5IH0R2FYOcmAZn2FvKxQ17ZJWCQVg7AepOPjEX068J2mDaml0CIAIlIlCo3eirQkfeYrHYnF13YADN39BT684QDB3c2aa2JB2oLqe9JZPJB8OiHvVOoJ1oYDO5wZF436mvtxutTqu92Twf2r3GAOhxJ32px00KdZyPBh+zPIC6CvedgHdZYty4ZZqEaZpt0+N8VAPVEAHpsJgesyAgTht1g+CdSQqgUNYLh0NHAccLwgYgJgEAEHwhBCOIhcG2XEgH1pfAEK7aJDXQfwbCoEEqAQAB3KhiH8P0uGAEgyJpCiqLQjD934btUSNE1VP-CDJxgXCYCY0zWPYziUCAA)

another edit (too long for comments): [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBASgewDZQLIEMIwLwwN7AwzoAmAtgJYB2AXPsedQPolQjoVIDOdXIATtQDmMAL6EYANyhUSCfnTxSZc-izYduvAcLES+AV1ZUQimIeMh17Tj3M6qI8eNCRYAQSRIAwgjIAjanQQCgQqLgAeABUYKAAPEBUue0FHAD4cfAkAbQBpGGoYKIBdOgAKXIBKbOKYAB8YCvqYTx8-QKpg0PCIgFE4gGMkIyhogBoYXLS07KoDAKh+Yuri4FFskuBXaBgAVSpuqIQASRNFrigBkLCI3YzcCTLd2ISk4iowGAB+RoBrOl2lWwaUkCAoJBgdCoUGk-EqL0SsmSZTK-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-BsAY-BUI0dnEMkrGVAAdB+4VcPIIBlBF5lglQZQAORjClQLYLgNG0tFsXxeFiXUKl6XwghFBcmUFBqTyZS9mOAETP4lTwpu-jhQ1MHcOVlXVRGdVfioh7DiuLXtiu4XAV1XA9Y0fW1XuQ38D2v4NUeo2tRI7VTaBthbR1-7TWsQA) for failure when adding a third type to the RolesMap when using the Type Guard solution, see line 35

Comment: so `roles` is an array and when it contains `"admin"` there is a property `admin_details`? And the array could contain both `"admin"` and `"vendor"` and then there would be both properties??

Comment: @TobiasS Exactly, yes.

Answer (score 2):

We could generate a union of all possible combinations which would look like this in the end:

```
{
    roles: "admin"[];
    admin_details: string;
} | {
    roles: "vendor"[];
    vendor_details: string;
} | {
    roles: ("admin" | "vendor")[];
    admin_details: string;
    vendor_details: string;
}
```

To make things simple later on, we need a mapping between the `role` and its associated properties and types.

```
type RoleMap = {
  admin: { admin_details: string }
  vendor: { vendor_details: string }
}
```

To create this union, we need to generate all combinations of the `roles` tuple.

```
type AllCombinations<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: K[] | AllCombinations<Exclude<T, K>> extends infer U extends any[]
    ? U extends any ? 
      (K | U[number])[] 
      : never
    : never
}[T]

type T = AllCombinations<keyof RoleMap>
// type T = "admin"[] | "vendor"[] | ("admin" | "vendor")[]
```

Now we can create the `Roles` union by distributing the permutation union and by creating a mapped type where each element of the `roles` tuple is mapped to its corresponding type in the `RoleMap`.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type Roles = AllCombinations<keyof RoleMap> extends infer U extends string[]
  ? U extends []
    ? never
    : ({ 
      roles: U
    } & UnionToIntersection<{
      [K in U[number]]: RoleMap[K & keyof RoleMap]
    }[U[number]]>) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never
  : never
```

The resulting type passes these simple test cases.

```
const a: Roles = {
  roles: ["admin"],
  admin_details: "0"
}

const b: Roles = {
  roles: ["vendor"],
  vendor_details: "0"
}

const c: Roles = {
  roles: ["vendor", "admin"],
  vendor_details: "0",
  admin_details: "0"
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBASgewDZQLIEMIwLwwN7AwzoAmAtgJYB2AXPsedQPolQjoVIDOdXIATtQDmMAL6EYANyhUSCfnTxSZc-izYduvAcLES+AV1ZUQimIeMh17Tj3M6qI8eNCRYAQSRIAwgjIAjanQQCgQqLgAeABUYKAAPEBUue0FHAD4cfAkAbQBpGGoYKIBdOlzs4pgAHxhPHz9AqmDQ8IiAUTiAYyQjKGiAGhhctIz4xNlk6gAzKH4YAFVYhKTiKjAKiSIAfgWl8ZJk9DWYHc2iGAAKfJr57KoDANnigEoKmDOiOiooaX4zr5+s2AomyJWArmgCyoLSiCAAkiZZlwoJ0QmEIvMMrgJBdFmMVkcwCdLgBrOjzZ7YNKSBAUEgwAG-Z57FYXC5kgpUGZzOGU6m0kjMnZwhkwb6-cHgSGIFDJXB1XwBIJo1okqBgBBTeDINCYUbLCac7m7fGGvipIQbbYmg0HGBW847cVA86ii5KD4wfg6uzzM6iGAAMihMPhiP4yNRLQiBFdRDynIWdwe-iepW1KAwEATwbVGq1Mt1EGK-uyt3uj34xWKaWZprt01mMAA8sSlAnCnnNS30828pUA4yXaLnX9gJ0wnxiHRC3KskRvbK6NkAESkShUFfFfoSdfMVg2LQwFcABhXwPBE-CIBg-hnPsysa9PuXK+ksnkW53RHfqmsmjsU9zwDdBklnS9JxvTp71lR8JEXKA7FXX9P0GNdGE3bcJBQtQDwAuggO-BgN3-WwCLPC8IVgDoBHQVFZ2iFlDSUBC7EJN5RCxDNEKYhsuSbPFbWSFiX1WdYBwkHZBP2Q41jOHYolXVit145JbhXZTKk9KTPSHOZ-jFQE-k+QyJWAKYDCoKMwgKLhCwifJ62SLsCx1LM0guViygqQYEH8AArGDEOeOg-P82yYBo-g6JABiRKXIYOIyJ9+DYAx+CoS4wuIWSwGeAA6Vj8q4eQQAuAr-NpKgLgAcn6GrKWwXBn1lYrSvK-LKuoWr6uZSiKC1C4KDsnULlXPdMMGfxnmZJ9-HyibSO4frBuGwsxrfFRP23W8ZvnW98pwpauBWy41tG5Ctv4Fc0Imr9dtmiR5qOvDbCehaMOO4EgA)

---

We can discriminate these union elements with a type guard.

```
type ExtractRoles<T extends { roles: any[] }> = Roles extends infer U extends { roles: any[] }
  ? U extends any
    ? T["roles"] extends U["roles"] 
      ? U
      : never 
    : never
  : never

function isRole<K extends keyof RoleMap>(roles: K[], obj: Roles): obj is ExtractRoles<{ roles: K[] }> {
  return (obj as any).roles.sort().join(',')===  roles.sort().join(',') 
}

if (isRole(["admin"], b)) {
  b.admin_details
}

if (isRole(["vendor"], b)) {
  b.vendor_details
}

if (isRole(["vendor", "admin"], b)) {
  b.vendor_details
  b.admin_details
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBASgewDZQLIEMIwLwwN7AwzoAmAtgJYB2AXPsedQPolQjoVIDOdXIATtQDmMAL6EYANyhUSCfnTxSZc-izYduvAcLES+AV1ZUQimIeMh17Tj3M6qI8eNCRYAQSRIAwgjIAjanQQCgQqLgAeABUYKAAPEBUue0FHAD4cfAkAbQBpGGoYKIBdOlzs4pgAHxhPHz9AqmDQ8IiAUTiAYyQjKGiAGhhctIz4xNlk6gAzKH4YAFVYhKTiKjAKiSIAfgWl8ZJk9DWYHc2iGAAKfJr57KoDANnigEoKmDOiOiooaX4zr5+s2AomyJWArmgCyoLSiCAAkiZZlwoJ0QmEIvMMrgJBdFmMVkcwCdLgBrOjzZ7YNKSBAUEgwAG-Z57FYXC5kgpUGZzOGU6m0kjMnZwhkwb6-cHgSGIFDJXB1XwBIJo1okqBgBBTeDINCYUbLCac7m7fGGvipIQbbYmg0HGBW847cVA86ii5KD4wfg6uzzM6iGAAMihMPhiP4yNRLQiBFdRDynIWdwe-iepW1KAwEATwbVGq1Mt1EGK-uyt3uj34xWKaWZprt01mMAA8sSlAnCnnNS30828pUA4yXaLnX9gJ0wnxiHRC3KskRvbK6NkAESkShUFfFfoSdfMVg2LQwFcABhXwPBE-CIBg-hnPsysa9PuXK+ksnkW53RHfqmsmjsU9zwDdBklnS9JxvTp71lR8JEXKA7FXX9P0GNdGE3bcJBQtQDwAuggO-BgN3-WwCLPC8IVgDoBHQVFZ2iFlDSUBC7EJN5RCxDNEKYhsuSbPFbWSFiX1WdYBwkHZBP2Q41jOHYolXVit145JbhXZTKk9KTPSHOZ-jFQE-k+QyJWAKYDCoKMwgKLhCwifJ62SLsCx1LM0guViygqQYEH8AArGDEOeOg-P82yYBo-g6JABiRKXIYOIyJ9+DYAx+CoS4wuIWSwGeAA6Vj8q4eQQAuAr-NpKgLgAcn6GrKWwXBn1lYrSvK-LKuoWr6uZSiKC1C4KDsnULlXPdMMGfxnmZJ9-HyibSO4frBuGwsxrfFRP23W8ZvnW98pwpauBWy41tG5Ctv4Fc0Imr9dtmiR5qOvDbCehaMOO4EgA)

Comment: This is brilliant, but I'm having some issues with it.  See the edit to my question for a link to an updated playground (link was too long to post in these comments). I'm going to be parsing these models from a JSON, so I need to be able to use "as Roles" to create roles, not just operate on Roles I define statically. Is there a change that can be made to this to accommodate that? I'd like to be able to just do something like `foo.roles.includes("admin") && doSomethingWith(foo.admin_details)`

Comment: @Nathan - I see. Check my edit for a solution.

Comment: It's not possible to use an `includes` implicit typeguard? I tried changing `type Roles = ...` by replacing `never` with {roles: []), but I still didn't get it working.

Comment: I've posted a separate question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73379910/954986

I'd like to understand why it doesn't work. I'll go with the Type guards for now. Thanks again, this is a really cool solution!

Comment: @Nathan - The problem is that even if this would compile, disrimination would not happen. So `t` would still be just the `Test` union, even if you did a check with `includes()`. Discrimination only happens on primitive properties, for example if `roles` is a `string` literal type. But not on arrays.

Comment: Ooph, I just ran into an issue. I can't add a third  field to Roles map (using the latest solution you provided). Playground link is in the final edit to my question, link was too long to post in the comments (and they don't allow link shortening services)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the edit? The playground looks the same, and adding a third field in the roles map still causing a compilation error.

Comment: @Nathan oops, now.

Comment: It works! Thanks for taking all the time to create this, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This examle matches your interface

```
// define all possible roles
const roles = ["admin", "vendor", "foo", "bar"] as const

type AllRoles = typeof roles

type RoleEnum = AllRoles[number] //"admin"| "vendor"| "foo"| "bar"
type RoleFlags<Role extends RoleEnum = RoleEnum> = `is_${Role}`
type RoleContextKeys<Role extends RoleEnum = RoleEnum> = `${Role}_details`

// flag key to context key and vice versa 
type RoleFlagToContextKey<R extends RoleFlags> = R extends `is_${infer Role extends RoleEnum}` ? RoleContextKeys<Role> : never
type ContextKeyToRoleFlag<R extends RoleContextKeys> = R extends `${infer Role extends RoleEnum}_details` ? RoleFlags<Role> : never

//type constraint for CreateRole<~>
type RoleInput = { [K in RoleFlags<RoleEnum>]?: boolean }

// wraps role input with context
type CreateRole<T extends RoleInput> =
  keyof T extends RoleFlags ?
  { [K in RoleFlagToContextKey<keyof T>]:
    T[ContextKeyToRoleFlag<K>] extends true
    ? string
    : undefined
  } & T : never


type A = CreateRole<{ "is_admin": true, "is_vendor": false }> //{admin_details: string; vendor_details: undefined; } & { is_admin: true; is_vendor: false;}
type B = CreateRole<{ "is_admin": true, "is_foo": false }> //{admin_details: string; foo_details: undefined; } & { is_admin: true; is_foo: false;}
type C = CreateRole<{ "is_vendor": true, "is_vendor": false }> // error
type D = CreateRole<{ "is_bar": true, "is_foo": false }> //{bar_details: string; foo_details: undefined; } & { is_bar: true; is_foo: false;}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&allowUmdGlobalAccess=true&pretty=true&ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEBMFMDMEsDtKgIYBtWgA4HsDOvYAjVJAJ2xNwFgAoAY23lwBdRzLQBeUAbQCJk4ALYI+AGlB8AbpHjhspcZOjZsSvoWSKAuilygGTZrVrMAnpiQBBdACUKkfd3OXs0Ng+o1TFpPZIAovAArkJcoDao-o48IUKEkKS6IALCogA+kjJyCnyZfCpq+ZqKPpag0QBiqMgA5rgAPNGgkAAezLLg+tFBoeE9cQB84QAGsLgA+gAkAN7RAL4jZX4OAMKMHe0A0pBmjc1tHXLdDr1h3AOhw9wjswsTUMzIsKi4S940IKDQNbWgANa7UDMbAGDaHAFA5ByUBSWB0JAyUi4ZCgZYVBzVOoAFWw63gm2YOzMTRa7U6JxIWPq1wqZKOXVAY0mswQ0ESGJI9IpnMgZ0WoAA-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-s5dl0UV7nMelXmgF8iTkKQ6IACI5aOsYFZMJTuZRpW0SlqiVZ57G1T5JRhbggWkMFobYONYEQfJ0HRSpyUlIl2mTKlHnpUZ6EfLQQA)