# VS Code: how to expand the "and more" type information tooltip in Typescript/Intellisence

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

How can I expand the tooltip to get the full type information for a variable?

I'm currently seeing this:

[image]

I'd like to expand the tooltip, or get another view of it, where I can copy the full type information.

Comment: Why do you need to copy it?

Comment: I'm having some difficulty with the type (using a pretty complex type), and I'd like to see the full expanded type. I think, down in the list, it's inserting some unexpected type.

Comment: Hm well what I do when I need to do this, is just use Extract/Exclude or mapped types to pick out the unexpected type. Tedious and tiring but it works. Maybe there is a VSCode extension to do this. But it could also help if you shared what you have so all of us can debug it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why this isn't correctly working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73378380/954986

Comment: Alright, but "not working" how? Is there a type missing? Is there a type that shouldn't be there? And what type is missing or what type shouldn't be there and why?

Comment: I thought there was a `never` getting injected there, but I was wrong. The type is what I expected, but array includes isn't working like I thought it would. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73379910/954986