# Typescript: Why does array includes on an array union type not work?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have the following type:

```js
type Test = {
  roles: ["nonProfit"];
  nonProfitPrivateDetails: NonProfitPrivateDetails;
} | {
  roles: ["artist"];
  artistPrivateDetails: ArtistPrivateDetails;
} | {
  roles: ["artist", "nonProfit"];
  nonProfitPrivateDetails: NonProfitPrivateDetails;
  artistPrivateDetails: ArtistPrivateDetails;
}
```

However, when I try to use Array `includes` on it, the type isn't being inferred:

```js
const t: Test = null as any
t.roles.includes("artist") // fails to compile.
```

It fails because `"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'"`.

IntelliSence is showing `includes` as a type of: `Array<T>.includes(searchElement: never, fromIndex: number | undefined): boolean`.

I think I'm just going to have to write custom type guards instead of using includes, but I'd like to understand *why* this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you are putting `roles` in a quantum superposition where it is every single type it can possibly be at once, and simply put, you are *never* guaranteed to get anything from that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union of functions or like here a method on a union of type, is only safe to invoke it with an intesection of parameters which in this case resolves to `never`.

Since `roles: ["nonProfit"] | ["artist"] | ["artist", "nonProfit"]`, there is no intersection hence the `never`.

One possible fix for that, make the role an enum / a type :

```
type Role = "nonProfit" | "artist"

type Test = {
  roles: Array<Role>;
  nonProfitPrivateDetails: NonProfitPrivateDetails;
} | {
  roles: Array<Role>;
  artistPrivateDetails: ArtistPrivateDetails;
} | {
  roles: Array<Role>;
  nonProfitPrivateDetails: NonProfitPrivateDetails;
  artistPrivateDetails: ArtistPrivateDetails;
}

declare const t: Test;
t.roles.includes("artist") // ok
```